# Custom sort for HashMap on Priority Queue

Tags: java, hashmap, priority-queue, custom-sort

I want to get the sorted key value pair on value, and if the values are equal, I wanna sort on keys asc.

I tried using PriorityQueue like following but I am getting null pointer for some reason. Please help me understand the issue and probably answer my query.

This is what I came up with, but unfortunately the output of the code is

PQ : [Hello, Yes]

Where as I was expecting

PQ : [No, Hello]

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>() {{
            put("Hello", 50);
            put("Yes", 50);
            put("No", 100);
        }};
        PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> {
            if (map.get(a).equals(map.get(b))) return a.compareTo(b);
            else return Integer.compare(map.get(b), map.get(a));
        });
        verifyPQ(map, pq);
        System.out.println(pq);
    }

    private static void verifyPQ(Map<String, Integer> map, PriorityQueue<String> pq) {
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            pq.add(key);
            if (pq.size() > 2) {
                pq.poll();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: @pjs thanks for the recommendation, I have updated it according to your review

Comment: Your comparator doesn’t make much sense, nor does your assertion that you are both getting an NPE *and* unexpected output.

Comment: 1) that code is not throwing NullPointerException! 2) Does not compile/run as posted! 3)   Using `compare(map.get(b), map.get(a))` means that `100` comes before `50` so the `"No"` entry will be removed first; try `compare(map.get(a), map.get(b))`

Comment: [ 4) be aware that a `PriorityQueue` only guarantees that the first element (head) ist sorted ]

Comment: @user85421 I wanted to sort it with values in descending order, and if the values in the map is equal, then topological sort on the keys. For the given example, I expect the PQ ordering as [No, Hello, Yes] when we pull out of priority queue.

Comment: exactly what is happening: values in descending order, so 100 (`{"No", 100}`) is first - 100>50 and 100 comes first in **descending** order - `pq.poll()` will remove the first element (the head as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#poll())), that is, it will remove `{"No", 100}` since it comes before `{*, 50}`-- why do you then expect the result being "*[No, Hello]*" ?

Comment: you still didn't explain the "I am getting null pointer" ?? but code as posted is not running anyways !!

Comment: @user85421 Please try and run the program now. You will understand what I am talking about

Comment: I did (obviously removing the superfluous parenthesis) - it is not throwing ANY EXCEPTION, even not if running online: https://ideone.com/59Hc3S  Can you please put the numbers `2`, `50` and `100` in **descending** order - which one comes first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use comparator instead of unnecessarily complicating things with priority queues?

If I have understood correctly, you want to sort by value in descending order and by key in ascending order.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Hello", 50);
map.put("Yes", 50);
map.put("No", 100);


map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry<String,Integer>::getValue).reversed()
                     .thenComparing(Entry::getKey))
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you only need the first two, just add a limit

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry<String,Integer>::getValue).reversed()
                     .thenComparing(Entry::getKey))
   .limit(2)
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks @Eritrean, I wanted to use PriorityQueue because, that is what I thought would help me to solve this with custom sorting order. But this helps a lot. Just out of curiosity, can we achieve this with PriorityQueue? if so, how?